# Emulate net connection without entering net dial

Tags: go, network-programming

I currently am working on vendor go balancer code. I need to remove the tcp dial call and emulate a successful connection without the call. In the code below, there is
this line:

```
ds, err := net.Dial("tcp", backend.String());if err != nil {
    log.Printf("failed to dial %s: %s", backend, err)
    us.Close()
    return
}
```

What this does is make a dial to the tcp server and then return connection
response in `ds`, which is defined here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial

What i need is to obtain the `ds` without doing the `tcp dialer`. I'm
trying to test the load balancer without any actual tcp calls. So,
essentially,
when we enter `handleConnection` wed create a net connection prior to the tcp dial and use this net conn, which should emulate 100% net connection before the tcp dialing begins.

```
func copy(wc io.WriteCloser, r io.Reader) {        defer wc.Close()
    io.Copy(wc, r)
}


func handleConnection(us net.Conn, backend BA.Backend) {
    if backend == nil {
        log.Printf("no backend available for connection from %s",
        us.RemoteAddr())
        us.Close()
        return
    }

    host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(us.RemoteAddr().String())
    _, ok := dbAuthTokenData[host]; if !ok {
        w := bufio.NewWriter(us)
        w.WriteString("InvalidCredentials")
        w.Flush()
        us.Close()
        return
    }

    ds, err := net.Dial("tcp", backend.String());if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to dial %s: %s", backend, err)
        us.Close()
        return
    }

    // Ignore errors
    go copy(ds, us)
    go copy(us, ds)
}

func tcpBalance(bind string, backends BA.Backends) error {
    log.Println("using tcp balancing")
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", bind)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to bind: %s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("listening on %s, balancing %d backends", bind,                                 backends.Len())

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
           log.Printf("failed to accept: %s", err)
            continue
        }
        go handleConnection(conn, backends.Choose())
    }

    return err
}
```

I tried commenting out `go handleConnection(conn, backends.Choose())` but that failed.

Comment: `net.Conn` is an interface, you could create a mock/stub for it.

Comment: @Adrian if it isnt too much work for you can you assist?

Comment: Try it, and if you run into a problem, post a question about it.

Comment: @Adrian k cool thanks

Comment: 99% of the time a test requires a TCP connection, you just use loopback. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: so just use 127.0.0.1. Thats not a bad idea

Comment: https://godoc.org/net#Pipe is useful for testing net.Conn in process.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it. But the only thing you want to test is what backend.String() does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you could refactor your code is to create a `Dialer` interface. In your code example you are using the returned `ds` just as an `io.ReadWriteCloser`. So you don't need to implement the whole `net.Conn` interface. As `net.Conn` has the read and write method inside everything works

```
type Dialer interface{
    Dial(network, address string) (io.ReadWriteCloser, error)
}
```

Now let's change your function:

```
func handleConnection(us net.Conn, backend BA.Backend, d Dialer) {
    // ...

    // Code here stays
    ds, err := d.Dial("tcp", backend.String());if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to dial %s: %s", backend, err)
        us.Close()
        return
    }
    // ...
}
```

That your production code works you now need to define a type `netDialer` which wraps the `net.Dial()` function. In your test you can use a `testDialer` which uses a `bytes.Buffer`.

This answers your question:

> Emulate net connection without entering net dial